# 'raise' inside 'try' , when and how do I use 'raise'?

Tags: python

So here's the code:

```
def fancy_divide(list_of_numbers, index):
    try:
        try:
            raise Exception("0")
        finally:
            denom = list_of_numbers[index]
            for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
                list_of_numbers[i] /= denom
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

If I call :

```
fancy_divide([0, 2, 4], 0)
```

why does it not print out '0' ?

and if I edit the code like this :

```
def fancy_divide(list_of_numbers, index):
    try:
        try:
            raise Exception("0")
        finally:
            denom = list_of_numbers[index]
            for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
                list_of_numbers[i] /= denom
    except Exception as ex:
        raise Exception("0")
        print(ex)
```

and then call the same thing, it prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-c1b0ac98281c>", line 1, in <module>
    fancy_divide([0, 2, 4], 0)

  File "/Users/dsn/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 10, in fancy_divide
    raise Exception("0")

Exception: 0
```

Why is that ? And what is the right way to / when should I use raise?

Comment: You have another exception in your finally. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: The `finally` block is run, a `ZeroDivisionError` is raised, gets caught and printed.  What are you trying to do?  There's probably a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Your `finally` block is raising an exception itself, a divide-by-zero error (because your denominator is 0). If a `finally` block executes as an exception is bubbling, and raises an exception of its own, it either:

1. On Python 2, replaces the existing exception
2. On Python 3, it wraps the existing exception in the new exception (creating a chain of exceptions, where the outermost one is the one that is checked, but the inner exceptions exist for context)

Your other code prints the traceback because you don't catch the second exception you raise at all (and it bypasses your `print`).

I'd suggest [reading the exception tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to understand more; your example code is so contrived/pointless it's impossible to say what misunderstandings you really have, and what is just to illustrate a specific behavior to support your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
def fancy_divide(list_of_numbers, index):
    try:
        try:
            raise Exception("0")  # 1
        finally:
            denom = list_of_numbers[index]
            for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
            list_of_numbers[i] /= denom
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)  # 2
```

*Notice the numbers*

1.This thing executes first triggering the `except` block outside the 2nd `try` and disregards other block.

2.This will be triggered as there is an exception in the `try` block.

Use raise inside the `except` block to avoid complicated things.

I would rewrite your code as:

```
def fancy_divide(list_of_numbers, index):
    try:
        # Your fancy divide logic here
    except Exception as ex:
        raise Exception('Something went wrong: {exception}'.format(exception=ex))
    finally:
        # Don't need to
```